# Script with docker-compose commands. A line is not executed

Tags: bash, docker-compose

My script looks like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

db_name="dh$1";
db_user="dh$1";
db_backup="dh$1-$2.sql";

docker stop $(docker ps -aq) \
    && docker start platform_db_$1_1 \
    && docker start platform_$1_1 \
    && docker cp $db_backup platform_db_$1_1:/$db_backup \
    && cd ../platform \
    && docker-compose exec db_$1 bash -c "dropdb -U $db_user $db_name && createdb -U $db_user $db_name && psql -U $db_user -d $db_name -f $db_backup" \
    && docker-compose exec $1 php artisan d:d:u \
    && docker-compose exec $1 php artisan settings:sync \
    && docker-compose up -d
```

Everything works great but the last line `docker-compose up -d` and probably the one before `docker-compose exec $1 php artisan settings:sync` don't get executed, and i have no idea why since there are no error messages. Any thoughts?

I believe the question is what can stop a script without error messages.

Comment: Start the debug by quoting your variables (e.g. `"$1"`).

Comment: You should add as the last line `|| echo "One of the tasks failed"`

Answer (score 0):

@Quasimodo for some reason the `d:d:u` command is stopping the script (after running successfuly). This is the handle method.

Anyways, i've set that command at the end since i don't need it before and all solved. Still I don't know why that happened.

```php
public function handle()
    {
        $this->checkEnvironment();
        $this->info('Pre-migrations');
        Artisan::call('migrate', [
            '--force' => true,
            '--path' => 'database/pre-migrations',
        ]);
        $this->info('Doctrine schema update');
        Artisan::call('doctrine:schema:update');
        $this->info('Migrations');
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        $this->info('Done');
    }
```